# Looking for a curve for calculating this integral using Residue Theorem

Tags: residue-calculus

I want to prove this equality using Residue Theorem

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\mathop{dx}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

**My Attempt:**

I used from variable changing $u=e^x$, However, I'm looking for a good curve which I couldn't find it yet....

Comment: And what happens when you apply $u=e^x$?..

Comment: @AdrianKeister Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Right, now I buy it.

Comment: Note that your integrand is equal to $\dfrac{x\operatorname{csch}(x)}{2}.$ Don't know if that helps or not.

Comment: My recommendation for a contour: $$\gamma=\begin{cases}\gamma_1:&[\varepsilon,R]\\ \gamma_2:&Re^{i\theta}, \; \theta\in[0,\pi/2]\\ \gamma_3:&[iR,i\varepsilon]\\ \gamma_4:&\varepsilon e^{i\theta},\;\pi/2 \ge \theta \ge 0.\end{cases} $$ Although, actually, you might want to come in on the $\pi/4$ line, instead, since $\operatorname{sinh}$ has zeros on the imaginary axis.

Comment: So maybe $$\gamma=\begin{cases}\gamma_1:&[\varepsilon,R]\\ \gamma_2:&Re^{i\theta}, \; \theta\in[0,\pi/4]\\ \gamma_3:&r e^{i\pi/4}, \; R\ge r\ge\varepsilon\\ \gamma_4:&\varepsilon e^{i\theta},\;\pi/4 \ge \theta \ge 0.\end{cases} $$

Comment: See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h354534p1922643

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=x/(e^x-e^{-x})$ is an _even_ function of  $x$, so $\int_0^\infty=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I didn't understand your contour.

Comment: It's the pizza contour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the OP wishes to enforce the substitution $x\mapsto \log(x)$ then we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx&=\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $1$:**

Now analyze the integral of $f(z)=\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2-1}$ on the classical keyhole contour $C_R$, where the brach cut is taken along the positive real axis.

Take $R>1$.  The keyhole contour, $C_R$, is comprised of the (i) line segment from $0$ to $R$ on the upper part of the branch cut, (ii) the circular contour $|z|=R$, from $\arg(z)=0$ to $\arg(z) =2\pi$, and (iii) the line segment from $R$ to $0$ on the lower part of the branch cut.

---

> Note that the singularity at $z=1$ is removable on the upper part of the branch cut.  On the lower part of the branch cut, we need to deform the contour around $z=1-i0^+$.  And there is a pole at $z=-1$ which will give rise to a residue contribution.

---

Proceeding, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_R}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2-1}\,dz&=\int_0^R \frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\log^2(Re^{i\phi})}{(Re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&-\text{PV}\int_0^R \frac{(\log(x)+i2\pi)^2}{x^2-1}\,dx-\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{\log(e^{i2\pi})^2}{2\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=4\pi^2 \text{PV}\int_0^R \frac{1}{x^2-1}\,dx-i4\pi\int_0^R \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\log^2(Re^{i\phi})}{(Re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi-\int_\pi^{2\pi}\frac{\log(e^{i2\pi})^2}{2\epsilon e^{i\phi}}\,i\epsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag2
\end{align}$$

As $R\to\infty$, both the first integral (a Cauchy Principal Value integral) and the third integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ approach $0$.  The second integral approaches the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.  As $\epsilon\to 0$, the fourth integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$, which comes from integration around the deformation at $z=1-i0^+$, approaches $i2\pi^3$.

---

Using the residue theorem we have

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_R}\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2-1}\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2-1}, z=e^{i\pi}\right)\\\\
&=i\pi^3\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Putting together $(2)$ and $(3)$

$$\begin{align}
-i4\pi \int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx+i2\pi^3=i\pi^3
\end{align}$$

whereupon solving for $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx$ we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{4}\tag4$$

---

Finally, using $(4)$ in $(1)$ yields the coveted result

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}8$$

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:**

Take $R>\varepsilon>0$. We now analyze the integral of $f(z)=\frac{\log(z)}{z^2-1}$ on the contour $C_{\varepsilon,R}$ in the first quadrant comprised of the (i) line segment from $\varepsilon$ to $R$, (ii) circular arc from $R$ to $iR$, the line segment from $iR$ to $i \varepsilon$, and (iv) the circular arc from $i\varepsilon$ to $\varepsilon$.

We define $\log(z)$ on the principal branch.  Note that $f$ has a removeable discontinuity at $z=1$ and once removed renders $f$ analytic inside and on $C_{\varepsilon,R}$.  Hence, we see that

$$\begin{align}
0&=\oint_{C_{\varepsilon,R}}f(z)\,dz\\\\
&=\int_\varepsilon^R \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(Re^{i\phi})}{(Re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_R^\varepsilon \frac{\log(iy)}{(iy)^2-1}\,i\,dy+\int_{\pi/2}^0 \frac{\log(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})}{(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})^2-1}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_0^R \frac{\log(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log(Re^{i\phi})}{(Re^{i\phi})^2-1}\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&+\int_0^R \frac{i\log(y)-\pi/2}{y^2+1}\,i\,dy-\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\log(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})}{(\varepsilon e^{i\phi})^2-1}\,i\varepsilon e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\tag5
\end{align}$$

As $R\to \infty$ and $\varepsilon\to0$, the first integral on the right-hand side of $(5)$ is the integral of interest, the second and fourth integrals approache $0$, and the third integral approaches $-\int_0^\infty \frac{\pi/2}{y^2+1}\,dy=-\frac{\pi^2}{4}$.

Putting it altogether, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}8$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: thanks, about METHODOLOGY 2, I think $f(z)$ is not analytical at $z=0$ !?

Comment: @SaniaSadian Well, we actually should deform the contour around the origin with a small quarter circle in the Quadrant 1.  That way the branch point lies outside the contour.  The contribution to the integral from that deformation component tends to $0$ as the radius of the quarter circle goes to $0$.

Comment: I've accepted. thanks for your answer,however, it would better that you use a circle around $z=0$ with $\epsilon$ radius

Comment: @SaniaSadian I've edited the section "METHODOLOGY 2" to add details around contour deformation around $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use residues when you can write

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x}{e^x(1 - e^{-2x})}\ \text{d}x = \int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x} \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} e^{-2kx}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}x e^{-x(1+2k)}\ \text{d}x = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2 k+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

Comment: The question wants to use residue theorem.

Comment: @SaniaSadian I can read. But since this is a large community, I thought that someone would have been interested in another way, just to say. It's always good to have N points of view ($N>0$) instead that just one!

Comment: I agree, thanks :)